# Autolayout constraints to make UILabel more sensitive to taps

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I have 2 tappable labels grouped within a parent view (The attached screenshot shows 3 of these views). Currently the size of each label is set to fit its content. Therefore a tap gesture is only recognized when the tap is directly on the text. I want to be able to tap above or below the text (but within its parent view) so that a tapped label is triggered. What type of constraints would I need to add between the views so that I’m able to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add minimum widths and heights to the labels, and that might do what you want (width >= minimum). Alternatively, you could add these labels as the child of a larger `UIView` that does the gesture recognition. You should add constraints to that `UIView` so that it expands as the `UILabel`s expand, and again, you'd still need minimum widths and heights.

Answer (score 0):

You would add a height constraint to each label. This is not normally needed, because a label has an intrinsic content size (`intrinsicContentSize`) that is used to generate its height automatically, through two low-priority constraints that cause the label to resist getting larger than or smaller than the intrinsic height. But if you simply add a height constraint, you can make the label taller, overriding the intrinsic content size; this works because *your* constraint has a higher priority than the intrinsic height constraints.